# Installing a JAR file

Tags: java, jar, installation, jsoup

I've just downloaded Jsoup from http://jsoup.org/download (jsoup-1.7.2.jar). The question is simple: how do I install it? I've already tried with right click > open with > C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe after installing the latest JRE version but it doesn't work. The jar file is on my desktop and I currently use WIN7. Some step-by-step "instruction" would be appreciated!

Comment: This is a library isn't it? Don't think of it like a program you install, think of it like a file you use. If you're using an IDE then there'll be an "include library" button kicking around somewhere

Answer (score 10):

Just include this jar into your project

For Eclipse:
1. Right click on your project
2. properties
3. Java Build Path
4. Add external jars
5. Find your JAR
6. OK, OK, OK

For IntelliJ IDEA:
1. File
2. Project structure
3. Libraries
4. "+" at the top of center colon
5. Java
6. OK, OK, OK

And read docs for this library.

Comment: Thanks. Do you confirm that the external jars are exported with the project?

Comment: It depends on what jar you exporting, simple of fat-jar. Fat-jar includes all your dependencies. But sorry, now I don't remember this piece, you need to google it.

Answer (score 2):

From the [jsoup web site](http://jsoup.org/) :

> jsoup is a Java library for working with real-world HTML. It provides a very convenient API for extracting and manipulating data, using the best of DOM, CSS, and jquery-like methods.

It means that jsoup is not a standalone java app. It's a library providing services that can be use/embedded in some other application.

So to use it, you have to add it to the classpath of your application and then you will be able to call some of it's API methods to perform the required job.

Note that there is an online demo of jsoup capabilities [here](http://try.jsoup.org/).

Answer (score 1):

For Eclipse Mars:

1. Right click on your project
2. properties
3. Java Build Path
4. Choose the library tab
5. Add external jars
6. Find your JAR
7. Apply and OK

Modification from Alexmelyon